# FastAPI uses sqlalchemy to create a many-to-many relationship model without foreign keys set, how to query the extended fields of intermediate tables

Tags: python, asynchronous, sqlalchemy, fastapi

**I created a Fastapi application with a self-associative catalog table model, a model for registering data table information, and an intermediate table relationship model for table information and directories**
**I want to query the is_show and order_no fields of a DkCatalogTableRelational model asynchronously**

```
class DkCatalogTable(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'dk_catalog_table'
    datasource_id = Column("datasource_id", String(255), comment="数据源ID")
    datasource = relationship('DkDataSourceinfo',
                              primaryjoin='foreign(DkCatalogTable.datasource_id) == DkDataSourceinfo.id',
                              backref=backref('dk_catalog_table'))
    name = Column("name", String(128), comment="表中文名")
    physical_table_name = Column("physical_table_name", String(128), comment="物理表名")
    logic_table_name = Column("logic_table_name", String(128), comment="逻辑表名")
    table_name_alias = Column("table_name_alias", String(255), comment="表中文别名")
    table_code = Column("table_code", Integer, comment="表编码")
    fields = relationship('DkCatalogField',
                          primaryjoin='DkCatalogTable.table_code==foreign(DkCatalogField.table_code)',
                          backref=backref('dk_catalog_table'))
    table_type = Column("table_type", String(64), comment="表类型")
    is_open = Column("is_open", Boolean, default=True, comment="是否公开;1-公开;0不公开")
    is_edit = Column("is_edit", Boolean, default=False, comment="是否可编辑;1-可编辑;0不可编辑")
    order_no = Column("order_no", Integer, comment="排序")
    creator = Column("creator", String(255), comment="创建者")
    create_time = Column("create_time", DateTime, server_default=func.now(), comment="创建时间")
    last_modifier = Column("last_modifier", String(255), comment="上次修改用户")
    last_modify_time = Column("last_modify_time", DateTime, server_default=func.now(), onupdate=func.now(),
                              comment="上次修改时间")

class DkCatalog(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'dk_catalog'
    name_cn = Column("name_cn", String(128), comment="中文名")
    name_en = Column("name_en", String(128), comment="英文名")
    catalog_code = Column("catalog_code", String(128), comment="目录编码")
    parent_id = Column("parent_id", String(255), comment="父级")
    parents = relationship("DkCatalog",
                           primaryjoin='DkCatalog.id==foreign(DkCatalog.parent_id)',
                           backref=backref('dk_catalog', remote_side='DkCatalog.id'))
    order_no = Column("order_no", Integer, comment="排序")
    is_show = Column("is_show", Boolean, default=True, comment="是否显示:1显示;0不显示")
    creator = Column("creator", String(255), comment="创建者")
    create_time = Column("create_time", DateTime, server_default=func.now(), comment="创建时间")
    last_modifier = Column("last_modifier", String(255), comment="上次修改用户")
    last_modify_time = Column("last_modify_time", DateTime, server_default=func.now(), onupdate=func.now(),
                              comment="上次修改时间")


class DkCatalogTableRelational(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'dk_catalog_table_relational_info'
    catalog_id = Column("catalog_id", String(128), comment="目录编码ID")
    tabl_id = Column("tabl_id", String(128), comment="表编码ID")
    order_no = Column("order_no", Integer, comment="排序")
    is_show = Column("is_show", Boolean, default=True, comment="是否显示:1显示;0不显示")
    creator = Column("creator", String(255), comment="创建者")
    create_time = Column("create_time", DateTime, server_default=func.now(), comment="创建时间")
    last_modifier = Column("last_modifier", String(255), comment="上次修改用户")
    last_modify_time = Column("last_modify_time", DateTime, server_default=func.now(), onupdate=func.now(),
                              comment="上次修改时间")
```

**"catalog_table_relational_oder_no","catalog_table_relational_is_open"** is an extra field of the intermediate table
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

**Sample query output**

**"catalog_table_relational_oder_no","catalog_table_relational_is_open"** is an extra field of the intermediate table
[image]

Comment: Please edit the question, never use answers to add information